# Who teaches whom -Astavakra or Janak Videhi

Tags: dattatreya, janaka, tripura-rahasyam, uddhava-gita

TripuraRahasya of Guru Duttatreya ends with Sri Astavakra Janak samvad where super wisdom of Contest Winner Astavakra is polished by Videh Janak as accomplished Ghrihastha.While Astavakra Geeta and most Saints preach that it is Janak who learns from Astavakra .Does Janaka also means any learned king later?